# C++ understanding typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

I have done some research but I just cannot get my head around what a `typedef` is.

I have found this example:

```
typedef HINSTANCE(*fpLoadLibrary)(char*)
```

Can someone explain what the `typedef` is doing here and furthermore what does it mean to have the values in parentheses

Comment: @Alex Nope, not a good duplicate. Find a better one please.

Comment: The difficulty here is probably more to do with function pointers than with typedef.

Comment: If you have trouble with the entire concept, you better start with a tutorial that covers simpler typedefs first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's clearer if you use an *using declaration*:

```
using fpLoadLibrary = HINSTANCE(*)(char*);
```

That is the C++11 *alternative* to `typedef`s (in fact, the standard says that - *A typedef-name can also be introduced by an alias-declaration*).
As you can see now, `fpLoadLibrary` is an *alias* for the type pointer to the function type `HINSTANCE(char*)`.
The types in parentheses are nothing more than the expected types of the parameters of the function type.
The `typedef` in your snippet means exactly the same, even if (my opinion) is harder to read.

---

Now suppose you a have a function like this:

```
HINSTANCE f(char*) {}
```

You can use the type above introduced as it follows:

```
fpLoadLibrary fp = &f;
```

Then you can invoke `f` also through `fp` as:

```
fp(my_char_ptr);
```

As an example, it could be helpful when you want to store aside a function pointer and you pick the right function up from a set of available functions all having the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `typedef` for a function pointer to a function with the signature

```
HINSTANCE fn (char*);
```

and used with the name `fpLoadLibrary`.

You can use it like

```
fpLoadLibrary fptr = fn; // << from above
```

Comment: but can you explain what it means to have (*fpLoadLibrary)(char*) next to each other like that?

Comment: @user3495256 What don't you understand in particular? `fpLoadLibrary` is just the `typedef` name for that case. It describes a function signature, and the `*` means to grab a pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef HINSTANCE(*fpLoadLibrary)(char*)
```

declares `fpLoadLibrary` to be type that is a pointer to a function that takes a `char*` as input and returns a `HINSTANCE`.

Analogy with a simpler `typedef`.

For an `int`,

```
int ip;             // Declares a variable.
typedef int aType;  // Declares type. aType is an alias for int
```

For a function pointer,

```
// Declares a variable.
// ftpr is a pointer to a function that takes char*
// as argument and returns a HINSTANCE.
HINSTANCE (*fptr)(char*);

// Declares a type.
// fpLoadLibrary is an alias for the type "pointer to function that takes
// a char* as argument and returns a HINSTANCE. 
typedef HINSTANCE (*fpLoadLibrary)(char*);
```